# std::unique_ptr and a template

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a scenario where I use CRTP.  Pseudo code below:

```
template <typename T>
class Base {} 

class Derived1 : Base < Derived1 >  {}

class Derived2 : Base < Derived2 > {}
```

everything works fine except when I introduce `unique_ptr` in to the loop. I want to have a `unique_ptr` to `Base` and elsewhere in the code use this to take ownership of either a `Derived1` or `Derived2` pointer.

```
// declaration - this is the problem - wont compile.
std::unique_ptr<Base> base_unique_ptr;

// cpp , elsewhere.
base_unique_ptr.reset(new Derived1());
```

or

```
base_unique_ptr.reset(new Derived2());
```

Am I in trouble? I don't want to change the existing codes use of `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Write down your defintion of the unique_ptr (as code not pseudo code).

Answer (score 6):

`Base` isnt a proper type. You need to specify the template argument for `Base`. I assume you want `base_unique_ptr` for Derived1 and Derived2, which is not possible since they have different base classes.
`Base<Derived1>` and `Base<Derived2>` are differnet types.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because `Base` is not a type. You can use `std::unique_ptr<Base<Derived1>>` for example to point to objects of that type. Also, the inheritance is private, so the derived pointer wouldn't be convertible to the parent.

If you want to have a pointer that can point to any instance of the class template, then you can give them a common base by inheriting the template from a non-tamplate base class.

```
struct Base {
    virtual ~Base(){} // don't forget the virtual destructor
};
template<typename T>
struct TBase: Base {};
struct Derived1: TBase<Derived1> {};
struct Derived2: TBase<Derived2> {};

// elsewhere
std::unique_ptr<Base> base_unique_ptr;
base_unique_ptr.reset(new Derived1);
base_unique_ptr.reset(new Derived2);
```